# Incompatibility with Implementing cbc solver in Python 3.11?

Tags: python, pyomo

sorry for the basic question, but I've tried a few different ways now and have gotten the same issue.

I had a script that I used to solve a problem using cbc on a different computer with Python 3.10.9 that I downloaded via WinPy. I've now tried to migrate this script to a new computer where I've installed the newest release of WinPy containing Python 3.11.3. The releases contain a cbc.exe file in the path noted below. In the older, working version of the script, cbc.exe was also located in the site-packages directory.

I'm calling the solver as so:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from tqdm import tqdm

solvername = 'cbc'
solverexe = "C:\\nnn\\python-3.10.9.amd64\\Lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\cbc.exe"

solver=SolverFactory(solvername,executable=solverexe)
```

And I'm receiving the error:
No executable found for solver 'cbc'

I've tried download newer builds of the coin-or and cbc solver from multiple locations, copying the folders into the site-packages directory and calling the solver in a similar way, but still receiving the same error.

I'm guessing it's due to the incompatibility between versions of cbc and Python?

Can anyone point me to a guide for getting Python 3.11 working with cbc?

Comment: the problem is not python 3.11.  I'm not a Windows user, but have you double-checked that the `cbc` executable runs from that location?  You should be able to navigate to that folder in a terminal and just type `cbc` and get the prompt.  If you just recently installed, be sure you log out/log back in to capture the new environment variables and try again.  Not sure if Windows terminal supports the `which` command but you can try `which cbc` and if it is recognized as part of the path, you should get that path and use it for your executable statement

Comment: `where` on Windows is similar to `which` on unix

Comment: The file ran via the command line. Would not having admin privileges on this computer affect it running via Spyder?

Comment: probably not.  If it runs on command line, then the issue is probably with Spyder

Comment: No luck running the script with the WinPy 3.10.9 package either.